# Can we convert a .sdf file to .urdf. I need to use the file in MoveIt. But it accepts only .urdf files

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Any other method regarding how I can use my .sdf file in MoveIt will also be welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6288/can-we-convert-a-.sdf-file-to-.urdf.-i-need-to-use-the-file-in-moveit.-but-it-accepts-only-.urdf-files./) by [abhi kashyap](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/809/abhi-kashyap/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-05-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

No we can't. Have a look at [link](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1310/sdf-to-urdf-converter/)

I think the only way is to start with URDF and convert it to SDF.

Some additional Info that might be useful

- Gazebo will continue to support URDF [info](http://answers.ros.org/question/147836/is-urdf-depricated-are-there-replacement-sdf-tools/).
- Also, xacro helps you to systematically develop your robot using macros, which I think is not there in SDF. So, it is not a bad idea that you start with URDF

---

Originally posted by [peshala](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/111/peshala/) with karma: 197 on 2014-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A unofficial SDF -> URDF converter has been announced in the Gazebo mailing list:
http://gazebosim.org/pipermail/gazebo-list/2014-June/000228.html .

---

Originally posted by [silvio.traversaro](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/455/silvio.traversaro/) with karma: 200 on 2014-06-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2